# Is there any way to fix undeleted files?

Tags: hard-drive, formatting, file-corruption, recovery

I accidently formatted a hard drive and then I used a recovery software to undelete the files.
I managed to get most of the files back, they're all with their respective sizes and folder structure, everything looks fine, the problem is that none of them is working. Even the text files, when I open them, I'll just get empty documents, but like I said, all the files are with their original sizes, for example, there's a video file which is 559mb, but will not render on any player.

I was wondering if they still can be "fixed"/recovered, something like that. I presume it is possible to achieve some results, since the files are not 0kb of size, instead they have the size they had before formatting the disk.

To whoever flagged this as a duplicate: this isn't about recovering data from a formatted disk. The post is very clear that this is about fixing corrupt data that have already been recovered (backed up) from a formatted disk.

Comment: Recovering data and it being usable are the same thing. The question is a duplicate. You don't repair files, you recover them as well you can. Well, you can repair, to an extent, but each file will require different repair methods and tools, and the odds of success are low, so the best solution is to recover them right.

Comment: I disagree. There are cases circumstances where file repair is a viable and perhaps only option. And in addition it is useful to discuss why/how recovered files are corrupt.